# Runtime Error in Java Leetcode #54

Tags: java, matrix

**Exercise letter:**

Given a matrix of m x n elements (m rows, n columns), return all elements of the matrix in spiral order.

For example,
 Given the following matrix:

```
[
 [ 1, 2, 3 ],
 [ 4, 5, 6 ],
 [ 7, 8, 9 ]
]
```

You should return [1,2,3,6,9,8,7,4,5].

**Given code:**

```
    public class Solution {
      public List<Integer> spiralOrder(int[][] matrix) {
      }
    }
```

**My code:**

```
public List<Integer> spiralOrder(int[][] matrix) {
        if(matrix == null || (matrix.length == 0 && matrix[0].length == 0))
            return new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int arriba = 0;
        int derecha = matrix[0].length - 1;
        int abajo = matrix.length - 1;
        int izquierda = 0;
        List<Integer> retorno = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while(true)
        {
            for(int i = izquierda; i <= derecha; i++)
                retorno.add(matrix[arriba][i]);
            arriba++;
            for(int i = arriba; i <= abajo; i++)
                 retorno.add(matrix[i][derecha]);
            derecha--;
            for(int i = derecha; i >= izquierda; i--)
                retorno.add(matrix[abajo][i]);
            abajo--;
            for(int i = abajo; i >= arriba; i--)
                retorno.add(matrix[i][izquierda]);
            izquierda++;
            if(izquierda >= derecha)
                return retorno;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the error Leetcode.com shows me:
Runtime Error Message:
Line 4: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
Last executed input:
[]

Comment: This is plain wrong. `matrix.length == 0 && matrix[0].length == 0` if the first part is true, `matrix[0]` won't exist, so you get your `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: "This is the error Lettcode.com shows me..."  Why didn't you include that in your question?

Comment: @bcsb1001 I did what you said, you were right. Now another error comes up. Runtime Error Message:
Line 13: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1. Any suggestion?